# Math.Round Midpointrounding.RoundToEven to 2dp why is it rounding to odd

Tags: c#, math

```
Math.Round(35.035, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) // returns: 35.03
```

The above as I understand it should round the number to two decimal places. The number is halfway between two numbers `35.03` and `35.04`.

So I specified round to even so as far as I understand it this means the last decimal place should be even so I was expecting it to round to the nearest even being `35.04`.

Could someone please explain to me why it's rounding to an odd on the last decimal place?

Comment: Just read this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360432/c-sharp-rounding-midpointrounding-toeven-vs-midpointrounding-awayfromzero

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423074/rounding-to-even-in-c-sharp

Comment: Problem is that you're using *binary* floating point but care about decimal places. You should use `decimal` e.g. `35.035m` in such cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `m` or `M` when you are representing decimals otherwise it will lead to approximation errors.

Try `Math.Round(35.035m, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven)`

Suffixes for different data types

```
float f = 1.2f;
double d = 1.2d;
uint u = 2u;
long l = 2L;
ulong ul = 2UL;
decimal m = 2m;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5898377.aspx

there you find the following:

**Notes to Callers**

Because of the loss of precision that can result from representing decimal values as floating-point numbers or performing arithmetic operations on floating-point values, in some cases the Round(Double, Int32, MidpointRounding) method may not appear to round midpoint values as specified by the mode parameter. This is illustrated in the following example, where 2.135 is rounded to 2.13 instead of 2.14. This occurs because internally the method multiplies value by 10digits, and the multiplication operation in this case suffers from a loss of precision.

Using Math.Round with decimal as first value solves the problem, but for the cost of type conversion.